# Idioms that mean watch your back

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am looking for an idiom or phrase that means to make sure your back is covered or to limit your exposure from behind. Something that connotes the idea of sitting in the corner of the room like Wild Bill Hitchcock always did. Would be nice if it also had a sort of cryptic connotation as well but this is not necessary.

Comment: In the US, the acronym _CYA_ (pronounced /siwayei/) is very common for all sorts of bureaucratic and political horseshit, especially where extra steps have to be taken for security and success (where it is possible). Though, usually, one doesn't have to worry about violence. **CYA**, of course, means "Cover Your Ass".

Comment: "Check your six" (a metaphor from clock dials) springs to mind but fairly reeks of cordite. And I believe "Wild Bill" wrote his surname Hickok, or sometimes Haycock.

Comment: What kind of "cryptic connotation" do you mean? Something linked to secret messages or cryptocurrency, or something that most people wouldn't understand or is otherwise subtle or hidden.

Comment: What's wrong with "watch your back"?

Answer (score 0):

"Keep your head on a swivel" is another idiomatic phrase from the armed forces which describes hyper-alertness or maintaining awareness of possible danger from all directions.